# Tinymce spell check implementations

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, tinymce

I have a classic ASP page that has jquery features and has TinyMCE editors on it.  I'd like to be able to spell check the editors, but every example I see is using PHP or ASP.net.

I came across this page: http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/tinymce-spellchecker-in-java/ but I'm not familiar with SVN, so I'm not really sure how to follow the steps, and I've read that it may not work well with IE.

Are there any other options out there to spell check my tinymce editors?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: @RogueSpear00 Sorry, I thought you'd see the notes below.  I got it work partly, but after I make the update to James Newtons's ASP proxy it's not working properly.  See my comments below.  Thanks for following up!  I'm hoping to get this resolved soon

Answer (score 4):

First, I'm not sure if this is even ok to piggy back off SG 86's answer, so don't chastize me if it's not...

I used SG 86's example, found that you're unable to directly use TinyMCE's provided spellcheck capabilities, but if you used the hack provided by a forum user, it does successfully work.

1. Install and set up TinyMCE
2. Follow instructions from forum user

All credit for this solution with TinyMCE should go to the original forum user @ http://tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=15662

---

I recommend setting up googiespell to work with a simple textarea with asp first:
googiespell is here: http://orangoo.com/labs/GoogieSpell/

the asp script is James Newtons's ASP proxy on this page: http://orangoo.com/labs/GoogieSpell/Documentation/
So once you got this working here's how you integrate this with TinyMCE
in your javascript setup the spellchecker config:

```
<script language="javascript">

tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    mode : "textareas",
    plugins : "spellchecker",
    theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "spellchecker",
    spellchecker_rpc_url : "/googiespell/spell.asp",
    spellchecker_languages : "+English=en,Danish=da,Dutch=nl,Finnish=fi,French=fr,German=de,Italian=it,Polish=pl,Portuguese=pt,Spanish=es,Swedish=sv"
});

</script>
```

Edit the line:

```
   spellchecker_rpc_url : "/googiespell/spell.asp",
```

to point to where your spell.asp file is located on your application

Replace the contents of spell.asp with the following code:

```
<%

Dim ByteCount, BinRead
ByteCount = Request.TotalBytes
BinRead = Request.BinaryRead(ByteCount)
rawData = RSBinaryToString(BinRead)

'get language
if instr(rawData, """params"":[""") > 1 then
    lang = mid(rawData, InStr(rawData,"[")+2, 2)
else
    lang = "en"
end if

if instr(rawData, """method"":""checkWords"",") > 1 then
'return mispelled words
 json = mid(rawData, InStrRev(rawData,"["))
 json = mid(json, 1, instr(json, "]"))
 json = replace(json, """,""", " ")
 json = replace(json, """", "")
 t = json

    r = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?><spellrequest textalreadyclipped=""0"" ignoredups=""0"" ignoredigits=""1"" ignoreallcaps=""1""><text>"_
        &t&"</text></spellrequest>"

    r = getURL("https://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?lang="&lang, r, "","")
    out = "{""id"":null,""result"":["
    wrds = ""
    for each c in filter(split(r,"<c "),"</c>")
        'response.write "<br>"&server.htmlencode(c)
        o = cint(split(split(c,"o=",2)(1),"""")(1))+1
        l = cint(split(split(c,"l=",2)(1),"""")(1))
        s = cint(split(split(c,"s=",2)(1),"""")(1))
        out = out & """" & mid(t,o,l)& """, " 
        wrds = "1"
    next
    if wrds = "" then
        out = "{""id"":null,""result"":[],""error"":null}"
    else
        out = mid(out, 1, len(out)-2) & "],""error"":null}"
    end if

    response.write out
    response.end

else
 'return single word corrections
 json = mid(rawData, InStrRev(rawData,"["))
 json = mid(json, 1, instr(json, "]"))
 json = replace(json, """,""", " ")
 json = replace(json, "en ", "")
 json = replace(json, """", "")
 t = json

    r = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?><spellrequest textalreadyclipped=""0"" ignoredups=""0"" ignoredigits=""1"" ignoreallcaps=""1""><text>"_
        &t&"</text></spellrequest>"

    r = getURL("https://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?lang="&lang, r, "","")

    for each c in filter(split(r,"<c "),"</c>")
        'response.write "<br>"&server.htmlencode(c)
        o = cint(split(split(c,"o=",2)(1),"""")(1))+1
        l = cint(split(split(c,"l=",2)(1),"""")(1))
        s = cint(split(split(c,"s=",2)(1),"""")(1))
        c = textbetween(">", c, "<")
        '{"id":null,"result":["Titmice","Times","Tines","Tinnies","Timmy\'s"],"error":null}
        out =  "{""id"":null,""result"":["
        wrds = ""
        for each w in split(c,vbTab)
            out = out & """" & w & """, "
            wrds = "1"
        next
        if wrds = "" then
            out = "{""id"":null,""result"":[],""error"":null}"
        else
            out = mid(out, 1, len(out)-2) & "],""error"":null}"
        end if
    next
    response.write out
    response.end
end if

 if t=empty then t = request.form()    'GoogieSpell is going to put the text in the POST data.

'show the reply from google for the POST data.     
 response.write getURL("https://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?lang="&lang, t, "","")



Function TextBetween(sThis, sAnd, sThat)
    on error resume next
    TextBetween = split(split(sAnd,sThis,2,1)(1),sThat,2,1)(0)
end function

Function RSBinaryToString(xBinary)
  Dim Binary
  If vartype(xBinary)=8 Then Binary = MultiByteToBinary(xBinary) Else Binary = xBinary
  Dim RS, LBinary
  Const adLongVarChar = 201
  Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  LBinary = LenB(Binary)

  If LBinary>0 Then
    RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarChar, LBinary
    RS.Open
    RS.AddNew
    RS("mBinary").AppendChunk Binary
    RS.Update
    RSBinaryToString = RS("mBinary")
  Else
    RSBinaryToString = ""
  End If
End Function

function getURL(aURL, anyPostData, anyUserName, anyPassword) 
DIM objSrvHTTP,web,method,s
    on error resume next
    s=""
    set objSrvHTTP = Server.CreateObject ("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
    if anyPostData=empty then
        objSrvHTTP.open "GET",aURL, true, anyUsername, anyPassword
    else
        objSrvHTTP.open "POST",aURL, true, anyUsername, anyPassword
        objSrvHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    end if
    objSrvHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objSrvHTTP.send anyPostData
    objSrvHTTP.waitForResponse 7
    select case objSrvHTTP.readyState
        case 0 'object created, but no URL opened
            debug "getURL("&aURL&", "&anyPostData&", "&anyUserName&", "&anyPassword&"): Object Created, no URL opened"
            err.raise 1, "Object Created, no URL opened"
            exit function
        case 1    'loading: URL opened, but no data sent
            debug "getURL("&aURL&", "&anyPostData&", "&anyUserName&", "&anyPassword&"):URL opened, no data sent"
            err.raise 2, "URL opened, no data sent"
            exit function
        case 2    'loaded: data sent, status and headers available, no response recieved.
            debug "getURL("&aURL&", "&anyPostData&", "&anyUserName&", "&anyPassword&"):No response from remote host"
            err.raise 3, "No response from remote host"
            exit function
        case 3    'interactive: some data recieved. responseBody and responseText will return partial results.
            debug "getURL("&aURL&", "&anyPostData&", "&anyUserName&", "&anyPassword&"):Partial response recieved:"
            debug server.htmlencode(objSrvHTTP.responseText)
            s = objSrvHTTP.responseText
            err.raise 4, "Partial response recieved"
        case 4    'complete: 
            s = objSrvHTTP.responseText
        end select
    getURL = s
end function

%>
```

Edit - Added my header for clarity:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "spellchecker",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,undo,redo,|,copy,paste,|,spellchecker",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    spellchecker_rpc_url : "googiespell/spell.asp",  <--! Needs to point to where the spell.asp script is located on your server. -->
    spellchecker_languages : "+English=en,Spanish=es"
});

</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this site alerts posters of comments, so I'm just posting here that there's comments below in SG 86's post in case they weren't seen.  Thanks again for your help.  I feel like I'm getting close to getting this to work.

Comment: What's not working?  I answered the questions above in SG's answer.  Did that not work? I read those comments from last week and responded.

Comment: The part that's not working is when I replace James Newton's ASP proxy with the new ASP code.  I'm not sure if I'm supposed to just edit his proxy with this new code, or replace it entirely with it.  I tried replacing it entirely and I get the spell checker on the editor, but it's not finding any spelling corrections to be made to words that it corrected with Newton's original code and no tinymce.

Comment: You need to make sure that the dictionaries are properly enabled.  And which mode are you using, simple or advanced?

Comment: I didn't edit the new asp file, I figured it was set up to do what Newton's did, but with the ability to check tinymce's.  So I'm not sure what to change to enable the dictionary, or what mode it's in.  I'll look through it, I just thought it came ready to do what Newton's was already doing.

Comment: You need to read the instructions.  1.  Add googiespell to your web directory (the one with all the script files). 2. Edit the spell.asp script in the root of googiespell to be identical to what's above.  3. Edit your originating script to include the spellchecker. See added example of my header in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the plugin spellchecker

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:spellchecker

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I noticed that but saw that PHP was listed as one of the requirements.  I'm still able to use this with classic ASP?

Comment: @Cineno28 - Looks like TinyMCE doesn't directly support Classic ASP for spell check.  It uses a PHP module for the spellchecker.  However, for the text box integration it does work fine.  Here is a link to one of their forum posts that has some hacks you can possibly use: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=15662

Comment: @Cineno28 - I went ahead and tried the provided example from that link, and I was successfully able to use the TinyMCE spellchecker.

Comment: @RogueSpear00 I'm not sure where to respond so I'm assuming it's here since SG 86 recommended the solution first? I got the googiespell to work with James Newtons's ASP proxy.  I then tried to add the tinymce's and the new ASP script that the poster provided, but I'm getting errors.  I'm assuming it has to do with the getURL("https://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?lang="&lang, r, "","").  Since this is on my server should I change this to getURL("spell.asp?lang="&lang, r, "","") or something?  I tried that but it's still not working.

Comment: @RogueSpear00 also, when it says "edit spell.asp to look like this" is it saying to replace the entire file with that code, or place it within it?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Cineno28 - Replace the entire contents of spell.asp with the contents provided.  You shouldn't need to make any changes to anything else aside from pointing the spellchecker_rpc_url in your script to point to spell.asp.  Also, you can post comments to the answer I've provided.

Answer (score 0):

JSpellChecker mentioned in the question (http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/tinymce-spellchecker-in-java/) provide few implementations of spellcheckers for TinyMCE and usage examples, but they all are java-based implementations (so you'll need to do some additional steps to make it working in your environment)

It should work just fine with IE, but ideally it should be hosted on the same host as the page from which you want to use it, since browser (not only IE) may block cross-domain ajax requests.

You may download code-snapshot here (http://sourceforge.net/p/jspellchecker/code/11/tarball) if you don't want to deal with SVN. It also contain usage examples

Answer (score -1):

TinyMCE provides

```
spellchecker_rpc_url : "/myspellchcker",  
<--! Needs to point to where the myspellchecker script is located on your server. -->
```

Here is Python Code (Write an equivalent in ASP):

```
  #checker is a pyenchant object - uses enchant which wraps aspell in our case . The code was taken from django's implementation for tinymce spellchecker.

  def spell_check(self):
        """Returns a Response that implements the TinyMCE spellchecker protocol.
        """
        try:
            raw = self.REQUEST['BODY']
            input = json.loads(raw)
            id = input['id']
            method = input['method']
            params = input['params']
            lang = params[0]
            arg = params[1]

            if not enchant.dict_exists(str(lang)):
                raise Exception("dictionary not found for language '%s'" % lang)

            checker = self.checker 
            if method == 'checkWords':
                result = [word for word in arg if not checker.check(word)]
            elif method == 'getSuggestions':
                result = checker.suggest(arg)
            elif method == 'learnWord' :
                result = checker.add(arg)
            else:
                raise Exception("Unkown spellcheck method: '%s'" % method)
            output = {
                'id': id,
                'result': result,
                'error': None,
            }
        except Exception:
            return Exception("Error running spellchecker")
        self.REQUEST.RESPONSE.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
        return json.dumps(output)
```